# AJAX only showing PHP variable if var_dump is used

Tags: php, ajax

I have html code returned as a string or an array (I've tried both) from a php function. I can only get the content of the variable to show using the AJAX success function if I use `var_dump`. Is there something Im doing wrong that is preventing the variables contents to pass between PHP and AJAX successfully.

PHP function:
*The variable `$display` simply contains html code for a table.*

```
//Display records fetched from database.
    $display = '<ul class="contents">';
    while($results->fetch()){ //fetch values
        $display .= '<li>';
        $display .= $id. '. <strong>' .$name.'</strong> &mdash; '.$message;
        $display .= '</li>';
    }
    $display .= '</ul>';

    $display .= '<div align="center">';
    $display .= paginate_function($item_per_page, $page_number, $get_total_rows[0], $total_pages);
    $display .= '</div>';
    return(var_dump($display));
```

JavaScript:

```
  $.ajax({
            url:"test.php", //the page containing php script
             data: {
                searchbythis: searchby,
                param0: name,
                param1: param1,
                param2: param2
            },
            type: "POST", //request type
            success:function(result){

                $('#searchHint').html(result);

           }
         });
```

Comment: The problem is your PHP code, not the JS code. Please show the PHP code.

Comment: `return` throws the value back to the call. What are you doing at the call? `var_dump` outputs. At the call, or after, do you `echo` or `print_r`?

Answer (score 7):

AJAX basically just loads the URL you give it in the background and gives you back whatever is *displayed* on that page.

Your PHP page doesn't display anything, so the AJAX call doesn't see any output.

You need to `echo` your response, not `return` it.

```
echo $display;
```

Comment: Thanks, simple fix. Wasn't sure exactly how that worked.

Comment: Just like loading the URL in your browser and reading what's on the screen, that's what AJAX does.  That's why you need to `echo` out what you want the AJAX call to see. :)